# how to show numeric data in seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am analyzing the covid 19 data in Seaborn, I have taken a specific state Maharashtra I have given the x='Dates' and for y = "Deaths" data = maha and color = g like this
[image: colde of mine]
but when I run my output of Date becomes messed up. like this
[image]
How do I show "date" as in date format like 2020-05-03,
[image: given_date]

Please provide a solution on how I can achieve this format

Comment: If you install matplotlib.dates and convert from the gregorian calendar and set the time format, I think you will get the intended result. `import matplotlib.dates as mdates;xticks = g.get_xticks();g.set_xticks([mdates.num2date(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in xticks])`

Comment: Convert your dates from strings to datetime.

Comment: @r-beginners i got this error                      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12296/3506935612.py in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib.dates as mdates;xticks = g.get_xticks();g.set_xticks([mdates.num2date(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in xticks])

NameError: name 'g' is not defined

Comment: @JodyKlymak how?

Comment: The conversion depends on your dataframe that you have not shown in your question. But in general, [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) is the way to go. For future reference: Don't post code/data/error messages as images. Post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: Add this: `g=sns.lineplot(...)`